# Conditional if and sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table which represents the brands and stock for last 10 months. WHat I need is:

Identify the SKU which have been sold less than 10 (quantity) for last 10 months.

The problem is that sometimes the december stock is 6 but January stock is 31, and if I subtract that I get -25. And this alters the formula and I am unable to calculate the products which have been sold less than 10 times for last 10 months.

I use the formula like below :

```
=IF((D2-E2)+(E2-F2)+(F2-G2)+(G2-H2)+(H2-I2)+(I2-J2)+(J2-K2)+(K2-L2)+(L2-M2)<10;IF((D2-E2)+(E2-F2)+(F2-G2)+(G2-H2)+(H2-I2)+(I2-J2)+(J2-K2)+(K2-L2)+(L2-M2)>0;"Overstock";"No Overstock"))
```

Thanks in advance !

[image]

Comment: Just note that in order this approach to work, there should be no addition of new stock during the month. Taking from your example - how do you know if you sold the december 6 items and have new stock 31 or just new stock 25 added to unsold 6 from december? Or (hopefully) you sold 6 december items, get new 20, sold them all and now have second re-supply of 31?

Comment: I understand your view completely but what I need here exactly is : rely only numbers which represents quantity of each month. We are not interested in between of this period. So, it is ok if we make the formula based on these numbers.

if for example december represents 6 and january 31 , then we need not to take this as sold and go to the next month (Jan-feb) and etc.

Comment: For example for Antonio Banderas sku - 10234 :
the total sold product is 30. we have ignored December-Jan because January is bigger than December.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to use `SUMPRODUCT` in order to achieve your results:

```
=IF(E2>D2,SUMPRODUCT(E2:L2-F2:M2),SUMPRODUCT(D2:L2-E2:M2))
```

Afterwards, you can simply use `=IF(AND(N2>0,N2<10),"Overstock","No Overstock")` to mark the amount as `Overstock` or `No Overstock`.

Let me know if it works for you.

[image]

Comment: Oh my God, you saved my life actually.. Was trying to find out all the day it worked finally with the help of you. Thank you so much !

Comment: One more thing:
if the numbers for all months are the same (for example 2) then the formula doesnt work :(

Comment: Hmm it works for me and the result is `0` - see [link](https://i.imgur.com/XLjMw29.png) What kind of output would you expect?

Comment: what I need is if the number great than 0 and is the same for all other months then I need to show this as overstock.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Can you use `=IF(AND(N3>=0,N3<10),"Overstock","No Overstock")` ? Alternatively, if you want to make sure that all values are the same for all months, do: `=IF(OR(AND(N3>0,N3<10),MAX(D3:M3)=MIN(D3:M3)),"Overstock","No Overstock")`

Comment: Yeah of course I can. But the problem with that formula is that:
If I use that formula another products like in picture are also taken as overstock. check the picture please. 

[link](https://ibb.co/wB20y8N)

Comment: I have a problem with the formula again unfortunately and need your help again :( 
check the link [link](https://ibb.co/Zfs7bVF) please and see there is still - number and even it  shouldnt be taken as "No Overstock" it takes it as "no overstock".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199603/discussion-between-orkhan-orkhan-and-justyna-mk).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use SumIfs()  formula for this issue

Comment: sumifs() formula can not calculate the row like that I think. Because how can you tell it that calculate the next cell if the previous is lesser than next one.

You should consider 10 months in this case though. for Antonio Banderas product there is 30 in total for example. How can we calculate this like that?

Think that, there are many fluctuations in 10 months (I mean increases and decreases)